# How to compare two dates & update model data in Yii

Tags: php, datetime, activerecord, yii, strtotime

I have a model named BloodRequest. When any new record has been made in this model, the status of the record is defined as "active". Now, I am trying to make a controller in Yii 1.1 which will check if the date saved in "required_on" older than two months. If it is older than two months, the status will be updated to "inactive".

PROBLEM: I have made the controller and it updates the status. But it updates all the status to inactive, instead of updating records which are older than two months. I have been trying to find where is the problem but couldn't. Everything is okay as I can see. The code of the action of the controller is given below:

```
public function actionRequest() {

//save all the record in an array
    $model = BloodRequest::model()->findAll();


    foreach ($model as $key) {
        $id = $key['id'];
        $date = date("YYYY-MM-DD", strtotime($key['required_on']));

//check the date and update status

        if (strtotime('-60 days') > strtotime($date)) {
            $found = BloodRequest::model()->findByPk($id);

            $found->status = "active";
            if($found->validate())
            {
                $found->save();
            }


        }
    }




    $this->render('request');
}
}
```

Comment: in your code ,basically you are changing status to "active" when date is older than 2 months. So it could be that all the statuses in you db are inactive and no date is older than 2 months so if condition is never satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to be considered is that the code could not be always executed, because memory limit. In fact, when you call `BloodRequest::model()->findAll()`, this could require too much memory (there could be thousands rows...).

So I think that if you don't need to execute particular task before or after updating row (overriding beforeSave and afterSave of ActiveRecord class), you could solve the task using direct sql, such as:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE BloodRequest SET status = "inactive" WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, required_on) > 60';
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```